# Extracting column names from several CSV files programming

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have 40 csv files. All the files have different column names. I want a list of column names of each csv in a table format(in csv or in excel). The new file should contains list of column names from each csv file and corresponding csv file name.

I am doing it manually for now but if the number of files increases, it will become problematic. I want to do it using code.

Note: It can be a very trivial thing but I am not a techie so please help.

Comment: This wont be easy to do with MySQL *only*. Do you have access to some host language as well (Python? Bash? ...)

Comment: I have not worked on Python/Bash but if these languages help, i have no problem to use!